# How can I initialize a string in C without knowing the length, and keep appending characters to it?

Tags: c, string

Basically I am trying to allocate enough space for a string as I extract out the numbers delimited by commas. How can I do that in c?

My algorithm is to loop through the string from index 0 to last index, and place each digit into a string called temp, and when I come across the comma, I print the string.

```
char* string = "123,4567,8910";
char* delimiter = ",";

size_t i;
// char temp[] = "" ???? supposed to be a dynamic string/array whatever
for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    if (string[i] == ',') {
        // printf("%s", temp);
        // clear temp string
    } else {
        // append the character string[i] to temp
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? It's the wrong approach, so the X Y problem. You need to tell us whether there are restrictions to solve this problem and what are they. Otherwise there is no good reason to do this they way you want to. Also, if you simply intend to print the string when you find a comma, just use `fputc()` and print each character right at the moment you find it, and when it's a comma print a `\n` to flush the buffers and go to the next line.

Comment: First problem, you don't understand [tag:c] strings. If you understand them, you wouldn't write `for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options...

You could loop through `string` and count up the number of digits, then allocate your buffer based on that.  It means you are looping through the string twice, though.

You can allocate a buffer with `malloc`, then extend it with `realloc` as necessary.  This only requires you to loop through the string once, but you're doing a fairly complicated memory management dance.